# Setting path for Borland C++ 5.5 and JDK 1.5.0 in Environment Variable

Tags: java, windows, compiler-construction, path

I changed my environment variable for Borland C++ 5.5 and run program there now I wanted to run java program sets the path in Environment variable,now java program start running there and again I tried to run a C program this time it says Unspecified path File couldn't found till I reset again in Environment variable for Borland C++. Pls let me know how can I set them  to work them together without changing them again and again.

On Windows 7 64-bit.
Edited part:-

C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.5.0\bin; for Variable path and variable name is "path". and for Borland C++ is C:\Borland\BCC55\Bin and variable path is "path"... I see when i change for others it gets replaces and previously set path get erased.

Comment: It would help if you showed the path variables you use... Without that it is only guessing.

Comment: Are you sure you want such an old version of Java? Java 6 is almost EOL and Java 8 is just around the corner.

Comment: set the path to include both `Borland C++` and the `JDK 1.5` and you should be able to run both. Mind you they're both pretty ancient to be using them on Windows 7

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.5.0\bin; for Variable path and variable name is "path". and for Borland C++ is C:\Borland\BCC55\Bin and variable path is "path"... I see when i change for others it gets replaces and previously set path get erased.

Comment: enviroment variable path can contains multiple "paths", just use ";" as delimiter. IE: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.5.0\bin;C:\Borland\BCC55\Bin

Comment: Thank you JIV.....May God bless you.